# Reduce number of calls of function

Tags: java, performance

I'm writing a program for a unimodal search to find the maximum of a row of numbers via `compareTo` and `Comparator`.

I've written the code and technically it should be alright. However, the runtime is too high. It should be smaller or equal to 28.

A tip was to create a variable so the function isn't called over and over again to reduce the runtime. But I'm having difficulties to do that. Can someone help? Here's my code.

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class UnimodaleSuche {
    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T suche (UnimodaleListe <T> Liste, int s, int e){
        if (s == e){
            return Liste.hole(e);   
        } else if(s+1 == e){
            if (Liste.hole(s).compareTo(Liste.hole(e)) < 0) {
                return Liste.hole(e);
            } else {
                return Liste.hole(s);
            }
        }

        int m = (s+e)/2;
        Liste.hole (m).compareTo(Liste.hole(m+1));
        if (Liste.hole (m).compareTo(Liste.hole(m+1)) < 0){
            return suche(Liste, m+1, e);
        }else{
            return suche(Liste, s, m);
        }
    }

    public static <T> T suche (UnimodaleListe <T> Liste, int s, int e, Comparator <T> c) {
        if (s == e) {
            return Liste.hole(e);   
        } else if(s+1 == e){
            if (c.compare(Liste.hole(s), Liste.hole(e)) < 0) {
                return Liste.hole(e);
            } else {
                return Liste.hole(s);
            }
        }

        int m = (s+e)/2;
        c.compare(Liste.hole(m), Liste.hole(m+1));
        if (c.compare(Liste.hole(s), Liste.hole(e)) < 0) {
            return suche(Liste, m+1, e,c);
        }else{
            return suche(Liste, s, m, c);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a note: Please, please use lowercase for variables. German grammar does *not* matter in Java (nor does English when it conflicts with the conventions). Everybody seeing `Liste.hole` assumes that `Liste` is a class and that it's a static method call.

Answer (score 2):

You have a superfluous call to `Liste.hole(m).compareTo(Liste.hole(m + 1))` just before the `if`. I think you can nearly half the number of calls by removing it.

Comment: thanks! that was it. Don't know why I wrote that actually

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite your code as follows:

```
public class UnimodaleSuche {
    public static <T extends Comparable> T suche (UnimodaleListe <T> liste, int s, int e){
        return (T) suche(liste, s, e, Comparator.naturalOrder());
    }

    public static <T> T suche (UnimodaleListe <T> liste, int s, int e, Comparator<T> c) {
        while (s + 1 < e) {
            int m = (s + e)/2;
            if (c.compare(liste.hole(m), liste.hole(m + 1)) < 0) {
                s = m + 1;
            } else {
                e = m;
            }
        }

        if (s == e) {
            return liste.hole(e);
        } else {
            T lowValue = liste.hole(s);
            T highValue = liste.hole(e);
            return (c.compare(lowValue, highValue) < 0) ? highValue : lowValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice thought (even when it’s an aside). It doesn’t work in this exact version, and I am unsure how to mend it. When I call the first, the 3-arg `suche()` with an `UnimodaleListe<String>`, I get a `ClassCastException` in the line `if (c.compare(liste.hole(m), liste.hole(m + 1)) < 0) {`: `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer`. Also I cannot find a way to add type arguments to your `Comparator` without introducing compile errors.

Comment: Found the fix: `return suche(liste, s, e, Comparator.naturalOrder());`. At the same time you may preferrably declare the last parameter of the 4-arg `suche()` as `Comparator<T> c`.

Comment: Thanks Ole V.V.!  you are right, `Comparator.comparing(liste::hole)` returns the comparator for `liste1.hole().compareTo(liste2.hole())`
not for `Liste.hole(m).compareTo(Liste.hole(m+1))`.  I changed the lambda expression to `(Comparator<Integer>) (x, y) -> liste.hole(x).compareTo(liste.hole(y))` (and verified this time).

Comment: I am sorry, with your edited code I still get a `ClassCastException` in the same line. And I still cannot find a working type argument for `Comparator`.

Comment: you are right about the ClassCastException.  I will come up with a fix.

Comment: Feel free to take mine from the previous comment. :-)

Comment: Yes, I think your original comment is right, it just took me a while to understand, lambdas are still confusing me.  I changed the code.  Thanks for the correction!